# Dashboard - for React and Node Js

Tags: reactjs, node.js, mongodb

What are the best thing to do to implement a dashboard with summaries, like chart, real time summaries like total establishments, total compliants etc.,

Also, I wanted to implement a inspection scheduling for the establishments, and had a notification reminders.

I am using React and Node Js here, it will really help me if you could suggest such as liblaries, code, or headstart

Looking for an advice